# Permanently sorting a table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, alter

I have made a connection to the mysql database and trying to sort two columns of a table as:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
import pandas as pd
engine_query="mysql+pymysql://"+username+":"+password+"@"+server+"/"+database
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_query)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("ALTER TABLE NG_Inventory_Inputs ORDER BY Contract_Name asc, Date asc"))
```

Above code is not showing any error but also respective columns does not get sorted in the table. It is same as previous when I use the following code to see the data of the table:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM NG_Inventory_Inputs"
sql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_query).connect()
data = pd.read_sql(query, sql_engine)
```

Can anyone please help me to sort the columns of a table `without creating another table` using `sqlalchemy` or any other library in python ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just add the order by to your select query?

Comment: This is not really a Python or SQLAlchemy question, it's a pure MySQL question. I would suggest not trying to sort via `ALTER TABLE`, instead make an index for the table with `create index idx on NG_Inventory (Contract_Name, Data);` and when doing the `SELECT` use `ORDER BY Contract_Name asc, Date asc`

Comment: Thank you @Iain and vaizki. I don't know why I was thinking to sort columns permanently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table, by definition, has no "order".

Output from a `SELECT` *can* be sorted dynamically via the `ORDER BY` clause.  A suitable `INDEX` *may* make that run faster.

Would you like to explain what your goal is.